# how to add pure javascript widget to angular framework

Tags: javascript, angular, widget

I create pure javascript widget:

```
 <div is="mywidget"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="my-widget.min.js"></script>
```

I add script tag in component this way:

```
private elementRef:ElementRef

let el = document.createElement('script');
el.type = 'text/javascript';
el.setAttribute('src', 'my-widget.min.js');
this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(el);
```

and add div in html but the script didnt build my widget inside component.

Comment: share the build error, I guess you have to add this js file from angular.json configuration.

Comment: I dont get any error ,if i add the div tag in body it build my widget,but inside component it didnt worked

Comment: share stackblitz

Comment: You can add it with angular.json, then you have to declare it like for d3 js I did this inside my component "declare const d3: any;". This will be outside of your component class.